# get the text file value randomaly

Tags: java

I have one text file:-

```
2,5,6,10,5,30
```

and I am trying this code to read the file:-

```
package str;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class getall {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
         public static void main(String args[])
            {
              try{
                // Open the file that is the first 
                // command line parameter
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D://Workspace_J/getstr/src/str/activity.text");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                String strLine;
                //Read File Line By Line
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                    // Print the content on the console
                    System.out.println (strLine);
                }
                //Close the input stream
                in.close();
                }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
              for(int a =1;a<3;a = a+1)
                {
                    System.out.println("get value from the file randomly");
                }
            }

    }
```

I can successfully read the file content,
but I want to read random values using a for loop...
How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to read random line from the file?

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the values into an array with `String.split(",")` and use `Random.nextInt(array.length)`.

Edit with code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        ...
        // assuming your string is "2,5,6,10,5,30"
        String[] tokens = strLine.split(",");
        // tokens will be [2,5,6,10,5,30], size = 6
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int a = 1 ; a < 3 ; a++) //a++ is a short way of writing a = a + 1
        {
            int randomInt = r.nextInt(tokens.length); // an integer between 0 and 5
            System.out.println(tokens[randomInt]);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry but where i add this...

Comment: You need to move `String strLine;` outside of the `try`, and put the code in your `for` loop.

Comment: where to put this for

Comment: The second one, see my edit. You should put everything inside the `try` to avoid any other problems (strLine beeing `null` for example).

Comment: problem in this line `System.out.println(tokens[Random.nextInt(tokens.length)]);``Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt(int) from the type `

Comment: You need to import `java.util.Random`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29

Comment: Please Check my own answer i update... and see what i do wrong...

Comment: add also java.util.random

Comment: My bad I thought it was a static method, see my edit.

Comment: solve i am add this all in while...

Comment: Assigning in a while condition is not a very good idea, you should use `br.isReady()` instead.

Comment: hey how to get first three value of a string any why to get this

Comment: I don't really understand the question, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want only first 3 value 2,5,6 in random function

Comment: If you want the first three values, it's not random anymore, so use tokens[0], tokens[1] and tokens[2].

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29):

```
String s = "2,5,6,10,5,30";
String[] a = s.split(",");
double r = Math.random();
int i = (int) (r * a.length);        
System.out.println(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am try this...

```
try{
                // Open the file that is the first 
                // command line parameter
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D://Workspace_J/getstr/src/str/activity.text");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                String strLine;
                //Read File Line By Line
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                    // Print the content on the console
                    System.out.println (strLine);
                }
                String[] tokens = strLine.split(",");
                for (int a = 1 ; a < 3 ; a++) //a++ is a short way of writing a = a + 1
                {
                    System.out.println(tokens[Random.nextInt(tokens.length)]);
                }
                //Close the input stream
                in.close();
                }
              catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html